# Prove that $R$ contains infinitely many maximal ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $\mathbb R$ be the field of real numbers and $P = x \mathbb R [x]$ be the ring of polynomials over $\mathbb R$ with no constant term. Define $R = P \times \mathbb R \times P \times P$ and the addition and multiplication as follows.

$(p, \alpha, p_1, p_2) + (q, \beta, q_1, q_2) = (p + q, \alpha + \beta, p_1 + q_1, p_2 + q_2)$,

$(p, \alpha, p_1, p_2)(q, \beta, q_1, q_2) = (pq + \alpha q + \beta p, \alpha \beta, \alpha q_1 + \beta p_1, \alpha q_2 + \beta p_2)$.

Then $R$ becomes a cummutative ring with identity. Prove the following results:

(1) $N =$ {$a \in R: a$ is nilpotent} is a prime ideal in $R$.

I've already done this!

(2) $R$ contains infinitely many maximal ideals.

This is what I'm having difficulty with. I at first believed $(0, 0, p1, p2)$ to be the maximal ideals of $N$, but then $(p,0,0,0)$ doesn't have a multiplicative inverse in $R/N$. Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $t \in \mathbb{R}$, the map
$$\eta_t \colon (p,\alpha,p_1,p_2) \mapsto p(t) + \alpha$$
is a ring homomorphism $R \to \mathbb{R}$. Check that it is surjective, then it follows that $\ker \eta_t$ is a maximal ideal in $R$. Check that for $s\neq t$ we have $\ker \eta_s \neq \ker \eta_t$.

Comment: I'm having difficulty seeing that this is a homomorphism. $n_st = p(st) + \alpha$, but I'm not seeing how $n_s n_t$ is equivalent

Comment: You misunderstood the definition. We have to check that $$\eta_t\bigl(p,\alpha,p_1,p_2) + (q,\beta,q_1,q_2)\bigr) = \eta_t\bigl((p,\alpha,p_1,p_2)\bigr) + \eta_t\bigl((q,\beta,q_1,q_2)\bigr)$$ and the analogous for multiplication instead of addition. By definition of the operations on $R$, $(p,\alpha,p_1,p_2) + (q,\beta,q_1,q_2) = (p+q,\alpha+\beta,p_1+q_1,p_2+q_2)$, and $\eta_t$ maps that to $(p+q)(t) + (\alpha + \beta) = \bigl(p(t) + \alpha\bigr) + \bigl(q(t) + \beta\bigr)$. Similar for the multiplication.

Comment: Right, I apologize. I just worked it out before you replied. My mistake, thank you for explaining.

Comment: No problem. You're welcome.